# How to find out when reading from hdfs is done in mappers?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I need to find time all mappers have received their input from hdfs. That means, let's we have 1gb data stored on hdfs and I have two mappers. Each time a mappernisnfed let's 100mb (split size). I want to find a way to find time last mapper receives its last chunk.

I was thinking of using a cleanup method however it may not result in an exact time because the cleanp functiom executes when the processing in the mapper is done.

Comment: There will be 10 mappers (not 2 mappers) to process 1 GB data using 100MB as split size.

Comment: So, you want information about only the last mapper which received the last chunk? Please clarify.

Comment: I need to know the exact time when the last chunk is given to the mapper. Because in my scenario, the HDFS is constantly receiving data and I'd like to know which data are processed in each job.